# Pandas - groupby ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was updated my Pandas from I think it was 1.5.1 to 2.0.1. Any how I started getting an error on some code that works just fine before.

```
df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Lake', 'Canyon'].mean().reset_index()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "f:...\My_python_file.py", line 37, in
>
> df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Lake', 'Canyon'].mean().reset_index()   File
> "C:\Users...\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py",
> line 1767, in **getitem**
> raise ValueError( ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Versions before `Pandas < 2.0.0` raises a `FutureWarning` if you don't use double brackets to select multiple columns

> `FutureWarning`: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead

From `Pandas >= 2.0.0`, it raises a `ValueError`:

> ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.

For example:

```py
# Pandas < 2.0.0
#             Missing [[ ... ]] --v              --v
>>> df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Lake', 'Canyon'].mean().reset_index()
...
FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
  df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Lake', 'Canyon'].mean().reset_index()

# Pandas >= 2.0.0
>>> df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Lake', 'Canyon'].mean().reset_index()
...
ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.
```

Fix this using `[[col1, col2, ...]]`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)[['Lake', 'Canyon']].mean().reset_index()
         date  Lake  Canyon
0  2023-05-02   1.5     3.5
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-05-02 12:34:56', '2023-05-02 12:32:12'], 
                   'Lake': [1, 2], 'Canyon': [3, 4]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)

# Output
                 date  Lake  Canyon
0 2023-05-02 12:34:56     1       3
1 2023-05-02 12:32:12     2       4
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found is to add additional [ ] like:

```
df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)[['Lake', 'Canyon']].mean().reset_index()
```