# How to get count for multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset I need to get a count of.

```
Manager  hire_request   hire_approval   hired   transfer_request   transfer_approval  transfer
 Adam         0               0            0           0                  1              0
 Blake        1               0            0           0                  0              0
 Blake        0               1            0           0                  0              0
 Blake        1               0            0           0                  0              0
 Chris        0               0            0           1                  0              0
 Chris        0               1            0           0                  0              0
```

I need to just get a count by manager. I tried doing `df.groupby(['Manager'])['Manager','hire_request','hire_approval', 'hired', 'transfer_request','transfer_approval', 'transfer'].count()`

Desired output:

```
Manager  hire_request  hire_apporval   hire   transfer_request    transfer_approval  transfer
 Adam         0               0          0            0                   1              0
 Blake        2               1          0            0                   0              0
 Chris        0               1          0            1                   0              0
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you want `df.groupby(['Manager'])['Manager','hire_request','hire_approval', 'hired', 'transfer_request','transfer_approval', 'transfer'].sum()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
cols_to_exclude = ["Manager"] #you can add here more columns if needed

out = df.groupby("Manager")[df.columns.difference(cols_to_exclude, sort=False)].sum()
```

Or, if you want to aggregate all the columns, simply use :

```
out = df.groupby("Manager").sum()
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         hire_request  hire_approval  hired  transfer_request  transfer_approval  transfer
Manager                                                                                   
Adam                0              0      0                 0                  1         0
Blake               2              1      0                 0                  0         0
Chris               0              1      0                 1                  0         0
```

Comment: **NB**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76158312/16120011) answer from @[*Corralien*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) explains why your code throws a `ValueError` and why you should, from now on, enclose with double *square brackets* the `[[columns]]` you want to aggregate.